# How to capture system2() output in R

Tags: r

Here is an example:

```
RR <- "/usr/bin/R"
x <- system2(RR, "--version")
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
> x
[1] 0
```

As you can see here the `x is 0`. My question is how to assign the `system2(RR, "--version")` output to `x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is described in the documentation for `?system2`. If you want to capture the output of your program as a character vector, set `stdout=TRUE`

```
x <- system2(RR, "--version", stdout=TRUE)
```

"stdout" is for the "standard output" of the program. It's a common term used by programs to identify the "result" from a program.

Comment: Great, Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am doing almost the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426902/system2-to-call-python2-and-python3-inside-r) but I am not getting the intended output, ideas?

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick! I was about to post my own question about how to do this when I saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `system` instead:

```
x <- system(paste(RR,'--version'), intern=TRUE)
```

Comment: I think this is for system() not system2()?